# Object destructuring returning nested object

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I have the following initialState for my reducer:

```
export function videos(
  state = { videos: [], search: { videos: [], term: "" } },
  action
)...
```

In my reducer I look for persisted state and create my new `videos` array with some persisted props:

```
case "VIDEOS_SUCCESS": {
  const { data } = action;
  let videos = [];
  let questions = [];

  data.map(item => {
    let persistedVideo =
      state.videos.find(video => video.id === item.id) || null;
    let bookMarked = persistedVideo ? persistedVideo.bookMarked : false;
    let completed = persistedVideo ? persistedVideo.completed : false;
    ....

    videos.push(newVideo);
  });

  return { ...state, videos: videos };
}
```

When I return my new state the `videos` array is nested in the `video` property.

```
{videos:{
    search: {videos: Array(0), term: ""},
     videos: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
}}
```

How can I get my state to look like:

```
{
   videos: (10) [],
   search: {videos: [], term: ''}
}
```

Comment: `return { ...state, ...videos };` try it.

Comment: *"How can I get my state to look like"* How is that different (other than order)? And what does the (10) mean?

Comment: @zynkn - It seems really unlikely that the OP wants properties named `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. on their state object.

Comment: @zynkn videos is an array of video objects so I'm pretty sure he does not want to spread it into the state.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, 10 is probably the length of the array.

Comment: @AngelPolitis - And yet...there's nothing in it. While that's possible, I doubt the OP wants that. Hence the question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a really active place, even on the weekend. When you post a question (or an answer! :-) ), please *stick around* for a while to deal with anything that comes up in the comments.

Comment: Side note: The only *destructuring* above is `const { data } = action`. The rest (and the part you're asking about) is property spread notation, not destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

Stores always partition state according to their reducers so if you call store.getState() you should expect that the returned state is in the form

```
{
  reducer1: { /* state of reducer1 */ },
  reducer2: { /* state of reducer2 */ },
  ...
}
```